# Message from Android to Android without Accesspoint

Tags: java, android, mac-address

I have two Android-Devices, i have no IP-Addresses the Mac-Addresses are

```
 d0:e7:82:fa:90:33 (a)
 8c:bf:a6:a8:77:8f (b)
```

how to send a byte from **a** to **b**? Is it possible?

EDIT: droped DatagramSocket-Sources because its packed-based.

By the way: Wifi-Direct or Bluetooth is not supported by the devices.

Comment: Broadcast your message using UDP.

Comment: But in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-networking/udp-datagram-sockets.html they wrote "*With UDP you just send packets of data (datagrams) to some IP address on the network.*". But i have no ip address.

Comment: UDP simply broadcast the message and every device on the networks get it, whereas, in TCP you have to have the IP of the receiver device and TCP does not broadcast it unicast the message to the specific device.

Comment: Got it, thank you, even the sender recivies the message!

Comment: Yes, Glad it helps. Posting it as answer so it helps others. Please take a moment to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As some mentioned, this is not possible without an active connection!

Because any other way will loose support and warranty:

I realy was able to send packages between those devices in 802.11(by filter uninterresting octets) without beeing connected but all devices must be rooted!

Another solution i successfully handled: was to download the Android OS-Sources and compile a realy own OS having modified permission-checks (loose of warranty).

Answer (score 3):

You can use UDP to broadcast message. It simply broadcast the message and every device on the networks gets it, even the sender. 
However, message delivery in UDP is not guaranteed, it may drop. So you need to handle that on client side.

Comment: No, the UDP broadcast message does not reaches the other android device.

Comment: As i said, message delivery is not guaranteed, it may drop. But its not like the other device will never receive it. Can you please explain what are you trying.

Comment: To use UDP i need the `DatagramPacket`, but i must specify a ip-address here what i do not have.

Comment: How without maintaining any network you are looking to send message? I think you need to re-asses your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use wifi Hotspot technology? Make adhoc network.
See [Create Wifi Hotspot Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152847/create-wifi-hotspot-configuration-in-android) or [Programmatically Turn on WiFi hotspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766425/android-programmatically-turn-on-wifi-hotspot) or [Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically)

Comment: This link has a n example: [link](https://www.whitebyte.info/android/android-wifi-hotspot-manager-class)

Comment: Sorry, if i do so, the device crashes and reboots immerdentelly! Also i said no AP.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 devices **should be connected** via any network, then we can communicate over **UDP protocol** using `DatagramPaket` and more from `java.net.DatagramPacket`

Note : If we can communicate between 2 devices only knowing their MAC physical address then what is need of **network** !!

This is contradiction against **Network Layer** definition

EDIT :

You can use **JPcap** application but there also your 2 devices should be connected via Ethernet. Check [Tutorial and More information](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/samples.html)

Comment: *should be* ... but they arent. Did i used the word "network"?

Comment: Wait wait, if i ever connect the two devices in a "network" my code works great! No problem here. But i need to message without Network!!!!!

Comment: So you need to use network.. this is what i want to say.. without using network, packets cannot be transferred.. Check JPcap application also and pre-requisite for running application

Comment: I dont need a packets, plain octests may enougth.

Comment: It is not possible. You are asking to break `Network Layer` ! Please think again

Comment: More.. You written in code `BROADCAST = Inet4Address.getByName("255.255.255.255"); <!-- no network!!!` but you can broadcast only if you are on _some network_

Comment: Ah, ok, so how to communicate without broadcast? Maybe using a IBSS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78169/discussion-between-kushal-and-peter-rader).

Comment: I think without network, you cannot send message.. you need any way to communicate between 2 system.. the way is `network` The network may be ad-hoc, may be without internet service anything

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is the rich wifi p2p api that android offers. Please see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

or for close range small packets: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

or for larger range if bluetooth supported:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: For using p2p, you need to use WiFi of mobile device, it uses `network` alternatively

Comment: p2p is wifi-direct, right? wifi-direct is not supported by the devices, sorry.

Comment: @PeterRader have you considered http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html (or does the range have to be larger?)

Comment: @PeterRader or if range needs to be larger then how about http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: sorry, must be in wlan-range. i actually am native programming a wlan-sniffer for android.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what we have [**`BlueTooth Data Transfer`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) .

Accordning to your criteria you should go for data transfer using BlueTooth .

Here is [nice answer](https://superuser.com/questions/623511/what-is-the-exact-use-of-a-mac-address) clarifies the use of `Mac Address` .

Here is sample project for [Android BlueTooth chat](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

Comment: Ok, i can not use bluetooth, sorry.

Comment: @PeterRader Ok . What is your medium for communication ? Infrared ? Serial Port ? & you mentioned that you can't use IP address & BT . Then what else ?

Comment: You can't use WIFI . Then how wlan ?  I think you should change your requirement

Comment: using NDK i compile things like `socket(AF_PACKET, 3, htons(ETH_P_ALL));` to sniff and inject.