# Android game crashes when attempting to start wifi hotspots

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, wifi, hotspot

I have two methods that will try to start the WiFi hotspot on the android device so that others can connect and play the game. The problem is both method have problems and don't work.

The first method:

```
public void ConnectWiFi()
{
    try
    {

        using (AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic("currentActivity"))
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {
                AndroidJavaObject wifiConfiguration = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration");
                wifiConfiguration.Set("SSID", meSSID); // string
                wifiConfiguration.Set("preSharedKey", mePassword); // string
                wifiManager.Call("setWifiApEnabled", wifiConfiguration, enabled);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception E)
    {
        T.text += "\nE - " + E.Message;
        T.text += "\n\t" + E.StackTrace+"\n";
    }
}
```

it crashes the game and I can't debug it.
here is the log for it:

```
    W/ActivityManager(  550): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
    W/ActivityThread(17070): Application com.thenightafterdoomsday.nomercy can be debugged on port 8100...
    I/Unity   (17070): splash_mode = 0 (integer)
    I/Unity(17070): useObb = False(bool)
    I/Unity(17070): onResume
    I/Unity(17070): windowFocusChanged: true
    W/ActivityManager(  550): mDVFSHelper.release()
    E/Unity(17070): GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_WorldToShadow'
    E/Unity(17070): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
    E/Unity   (17070): (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    E/Unity   (17070):
    E/Unity   (17070): GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_WorldToShadow'
    E/Unity   (17070): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
    E/Unity   (17070): (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    E/Unity   (17070):
    E/Unity   (17070): -------- GLSL link error: ERROR:LEX/PARSE-2 (line 38) Undefined identifier
    E/Unity   (17070):
    E/Unity   (17070):
    E/Unity   (17070): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
    E/Unity   (17070): (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/ApiGLES.cpp Line: 685)
    E/Unity   (17070):
    E/Unity   (17070): GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_LightColor'
    E/Unity   (17070): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
    E/Unity   (17070): (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    E/Unity   (17070):
    E/Unity   (17070): GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_LightPosition'
    E/Unity   (17070): Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
    E/Unity   (17070): (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    E/Unity   (17070):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    I/DEBUG   (15581): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/baffinxx/baffin:4.2.2/JDQ39/I9082XXUBNC1:user/release-keys'
    I/DEBUG   (15581): Revision: '5'
    I/DEBUG   (15581): pid: 17070, tid: 17086, name: UnityMain  >>> com.thenightafterdoomsday.nomercy 
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): stack:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1c8  41c0f648  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1cc  41c0f648  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1d0  4103b3b8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1d4  4103b460
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1d8  4103b3b8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1dc  40991ebf  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmReleaseTrackedAlloc+30)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1e0  56b4d20c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1e4  4ca4a564  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1e8  49334a40
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1ec  00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1f0  4ca4a564  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1f4  4098723f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+34)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1f8  00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d1fc  4ca4a564  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d200 df0027ad
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d204  00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     #00  56b4d208  49334a40
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d20c  4103b3b8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d210  4ca4a564  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d214  409885a7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d218  00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d21c  49334a40
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d220  56b4d22c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d224  55fe752c  /mnt/asec/com.thenightafterdoomsday.nomercy-1/lib/libunity.so (AndroidJNI_CUSTOM_SetStringField(void*, void*, ICallString)+284)
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     #01  56b4d228  49588ee0
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d22c  50c7396c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d230  20c0000d
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d234  41135c00
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d238  49334a40
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d23c  4984fd20
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d240  56948d9c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d244  49591ed8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d248  55527c20  /mnt/asec/com.thenightafterdoomsday.nomercy-1/lib/libmono.so
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d24c  56b4da70
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d250  00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d254 ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d258  50c29170
    I/DEBUG   (15581):          56b4d25c  50c95048
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     #02  56b4d260  00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near r0:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f628 00000009 00000000 00700077 00530073
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f638 00610074 00750074 00000073 00000023
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f648 412400e0 00000000 41c0f668 3920c217
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f658 00000000 00000009 00000000 0000002b
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f668 41240950 00000000 00000009 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f678 0065004d 006f0048 00530074 006f0070
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f688 00000074 00000043 41243308 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f698 00000000 41a83978 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f6a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 4123f2a8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f6b8 41c0f6e8 41c0f6d0 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f6c8 00000000 0000001b 4123fc98 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f6d8 00000001 00000000 4123f698 00000023
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f6e8 412400e0 00000000 41c0f708 6b68cba2
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f6f8 00000000 00000007 00000000 0000002b
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f708 41240950 00000000 00000007 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     41c0f718 006f0064 00720046 006d0061 00000065
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near r5:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a544 4f36ba3e 00000001 00000014 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a554 4f32e24d 4f36ba3e 00000001 00000018
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a564 41c0b228 4f385c1b 4f36ba3e 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a574 0000001c 41c0b228 4f3b5ea8 4f36d0d7
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a584 00000001 00000020 41c0b228 4f3b5edc
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a594 4f36d0d7 00000001 00000024 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5a4 4f3b5f0c 4f36d0d7 00000001 00000028
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5b4 41c0b228 4f3b5f3e 4f36d0d7 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5c4 0000002c 41c0b228 4f3b5f74 4f36d0d7
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5d4 00000001 00000030 41c0b228 4f3b9d65
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5e4 4f34a1a3 00000001 00000034 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5f4 4f43ba11 4f3b13e3 00000001 00000038
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a604 41c0b228 4f43b70d 4f36ba3e 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a614 0000003c 41c0b228 4f3bd46a 4f34a1a3
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a624 00000001 00000040 41c0b228 4f43b699
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a634 4f36ba3e 00000001 00000044 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near r6:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a20 006e0061 0000001b 41b8d070 696e752f
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a30 64337974 616c702f 2f726579 00000023
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a40 409e4328 00000000 0000000b 4103b3b8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a50 00000000 4c4e8908 4c4dc658 00000023
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a60 41b8d070 40150c74 0000003b 00000011
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a70 00000000 00000000 00000020 00000023
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a80 000f0284 00200011 0b0a0909 0b09090d
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334a90 0a080a0c 00000d0b 00000020 0000001b
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334aa0 00090184 0904000a 0a080909 000c1511
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334ab0 00000018 0000004b 00110000 40150c9c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334ac0 00720065 00630069 002f0061 00610042
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334ad0 00690068 005f0061 00610042 0064006e
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334ae0 00720065 00730061 00000000 0001010a
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334af0 006ddd00 00000000 00000048 00000013
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334b00 00000001 00000000 4932cbe8 0000001b
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     49334b10 00000002 00000000 4932cbe8 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near r7:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20bfffec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20bffffc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0000c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0001c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0002c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0003c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0004c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0005c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0006c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0007c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0008c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c0009c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c000ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c000bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c000cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     20c000dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near r8:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a544 4f36ba3e 00000001 00000014 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a554 4f32e24d 4f36ba3e 00000001 00000018
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a564 41c0b228 4f385c1b 4f36ba3e 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a574 0000001c 41c0b228 4f3b5ea8 4f36d0d7
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a584 00000001 00000020 41c0b228 4f3b5edc
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a594 4f36d0d7 00000001 00000024 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5a4 4f3b5f0c 4f36d0d7 00000001 00000028
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5b4 41c0b228 4f3b5f3e 4f36d0d7 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5c4 0000002c 41c0b228 4f3b5f74 4f36d0d7
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5d4 00000001 00000030 41c0b228 4f3b9d65
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5e4 4f34a1a3 00000001 00000034 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a5f4 4f43ba11 4f3b13e3 00000001 00000038
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a604 41c0b228 4f43b70d 4f36ba3e 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a614 0000003c 41c0b228 4f3bd46a 4f34a1a3
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a624 00000001 00000040 41c0b228 4f43b699
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4ca4a634 4f36ba3e 00000001 00000044 41c0b228
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near r9:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce8a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce8b0 00000000 00000000 00004000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce8c0 00000101 00000001 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce8d0 00000000 565b5fe5 00000008 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce8e0 00000000 565de63a 00000000 565de649
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce8f0 00000000 565de661 00000001 565de672
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce900 0000000d 565de683 0000000f 565de69b
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce910 0000000f 565de6b4 0000000f 565de6cf
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce920 0000000b 565de6e2 0000000f 565de6f3
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce930 00000001 565de70a 00000000 565de71b
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce940 0000000f 00000000 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce950 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce960 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce970 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce980 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     568ce990 00000001 00000000 49332110 00000025
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near sl:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168e90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168ea0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168eb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168ec0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168ed0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168ee0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168ef0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168f00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168f10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     00168f20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near fp:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d240 56948d9c 49591ed8 55527c20 56b4da70
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d250 00000001 ffffffff 50c29170 50c95048
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d260 00000000 4ca4a564 4984fd20 41203070
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d270 41135cf8 41135c30 50c6db90 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d280 56b4d260 50c95000 56b4d294 553d56e4
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d290 56b4d328 00000000 41135cf8 41135c28
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2a0 56b4d2c4 551aee54 56b4d298 50c949e4
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2b0 1d2003ca 41135c28 49850b98 56b4d2c8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2c0 56b4d300 41203018 00000000 4ca4a564
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2d0 4984fd20 00000000 55527c20 56b4da70
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2e0 00000001 ffffffff 50c29170 568ce8c0
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2f0 00168e50 56b4d300 56b4d300 50c94ef4
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d300 55527c20 56b4da70 00000001 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d310 4ca4a564 4984fd20 50c29170 56b4d328
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d320 56b4d328 50c949e4 56b4d3c0 41135c28
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d330 4ca4a564 00000000 50c27f40 4984fd20
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): memory near sp:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d1e8 49334a40 00000000 4ca4a564 4098723f
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d1f8 00000000 4ca4a564 df0027ad 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d208 49334a40 4103b3b8 4ca4a564 409885a7
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d218 00000000 49334a40 56b4d22c 55fe752c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d228 49588ee0 50c7396c 20c0000d 41135c00
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d238 49334a40 4984fd20 56948d9c 49591ed8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d248 55527c20 56b4da70 00000001 ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d258 50c29170 50c95048 00000000 4ca4a564
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d268 4984fd20 41203070 41135cf8 41135c30
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d278 50c6db90 00000001 56b4d260 50c95000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d288 56b4d294 553d56e4 56b4d328 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d298 41135cf8 41135c28 56b4d2c4 551aee54
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2a8 56b4d298 50c949e4 1d2003ca 41135c28
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2b8 49850b98 56b4d2c8 56b4d300 41203018
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2c8 00000000 4ca4a564 4984fd20 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     56b4d2d8 55527c20 56b4da70 00000001 ffffffff
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): code around pc:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409885c4 4604065b d5089801 fe26f7fe f3bf6929
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409885d4 50608f5e 8f5ff3bf f7fee003 692afe1d
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409885e4 b11050a0 f0094620 a801ff0d fe3cf7fd
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409885f4 4684bdfe 460cb537 4661a801 f7fd4615
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988604 9801fe0f f7fe4621 68ebfe07 0f40f013
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988614 d007692b f7dc18c0 4604eac4 f3bf460d
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988624 e0028f5f e9d018c0 a8014500 fe1cf7fd
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988634 46294620 bd30b003 b5374684 a801460c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988644 46154661 fdecf7fd 98014621 fde4f7fe
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988654 f01368eb 692b0f40 18c3bf04 d002681c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988664 f3bf58c4 a8018f5f fdfef7fd bd3e4620
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988674 b5374684 a801460c 46154661 fdd0f7fd
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988684 98014621 fdc8f7fe f01368eb 692b0f40
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     40988694 18c2bf02 685558c4 18c0d006 ea80f7dc
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409886a4 460d4604 8f5ff3bf f7fda801 4620fddd
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409886b4 b0034629 4684bd30 460cb537 4661a801
    I/DEBUG   (15581):
    I/DEBUG   (15581): code around lr:
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098721c b5704b39 460e447b d0652900 0203f001
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098722c d0142a02 d02c2a03 d14b2a01 f7de30a8
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098723c 4604e950 d1582800 46334930 20064a30
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098724c 447a4479 eb68f7d3 fd1af7fb 4a2de04d
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098725c f505589d f7d37056 f505eb96 4631704c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098726c e936f7de b9484604 46334927 20064a27
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098727c 447a4479 eb50f7d3 fd02f7fb 7056f505
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098728c 4820e01d f505581d f7d37057 f505eb7c
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098729c 46317051 e91cf7de 42984b15 d00b4604
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409872ac 491bb958 4a1b4633 44792006 f7d3447a
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409872bc f7fbeb34 e000fce5 f5052400 f7d37057
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409872cc e012eb68 c050f8df 400cf853 b95978e1
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409872dc 46334912 20054a12 4c064479 f7d3447a
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409872ec f7fbeb1c e000fccd 46204634 bf00bd70
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     409872fc dead1234 dead4321 0005fa74 000440b2
    I/DEBUG   (15581):     4098730c 000488f8 fffffe60 00044082 00048901
    I/DEBUG   (15581): !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 17070
    I/ActivityManager(  550): Process com.thenightafterdoomsday.nomercy (pid 17070) (adj 0) has died.
    W/ActivityManager(  550): Force removing ActivityRecord { 42f5eb80 u0 com.thenightafterdoomsday.nomercy / com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: app died, no saved state
    W/ActivityManager(  550): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
    W/ActivityManager(  550): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10030
    W/ActivityManager(  550): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10031
    W/ActivityManager(  550): mDVFSHelper.release()
    E/dalvikvm(  128): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=312
```

I filtered it to what I thought would be helpful...
The Second method:

```
public void ConnectWiFiHardWay()
{
    try
    {

        using (AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic("currentActivity"))
        {
            using (var wifiManager = activity.Call("getSystemService", "wifi"))
            {

                using (AndroidJavaObject classObj = wifiManager.Call("getClass"))
                {
                    using (AndroidJavaObject wifiConfiguration = new AndroidJavaObject("setWifiApEnabled"))
                    {
                        wifiConfiguration.Set("SSID", meSSID); // string
                        wifiConfiguration.Set("preSharedKey", mePassword); 
                        using (AndroidJavaObject wifiCfgClass = wifiConfiguration.Call("getClass"))
                        {
                            using (AndroidJavaObject booleanObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.Boolean"))
                            {
                                using (AndroidJavaObject booleanClass = booleanObj.Call("getClass"))
                                using (AndroidJavaObject methodObj = classObj.Call("getMethod", "setWifiApEnabled", wifiCfgClass, booleanClass))
                                {
                                    methodObj.Call("invoke", wifiManager, wifiConfiguration, enabled);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception E)
    {
        T.text += "\nH - " + E.Message;
        T.text += "\n\t" + E.StackTrace+"\n";
    }
```

this one throws an exception that says `setWifiApEnabled` Cannot be found
I can post the complete error text if that helps.
Also I followed [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697725/turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically) instructions.

Comment: Please share the ctash logs

Comment: what is ctash? for the first one or the second?@Fairoz

Comment: Sorry it was crash logs?

Comment: I added the logs @Fairoz, see if it helps